# JavaScript split function

Tags: javascript

i like to split a string depending on "," character using JavaScript

example

```
var mystring="1=name1,2=name2,3=name3";
```

need output like this

```
1=name1
2=name2
3=name3
```

Comment: -1: A Google search for exactly this phrase ("JavaScript split function") would have yielded several results explaining how to do this.

Comment: +1 I rely on StackOverflow because I trust the community to have concise, correct answers to simple questions like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var list = mystring.split(',');
```

Now you have an array with `['1=name1', '2=name2', '3=name3']`

If you then want to output it all separated by spaces you can do:

```
var spaces = list.join("\n");
```

Of course, if that's really the ultimate goal, you could also just replace commas with spaces:

```
var spaces = mystring.replace(/,/g, "\n");
```

(Edit: Your original post didn't have your intended output in a code block, so I thought you were after spaces. Fortunately, the same techniques work to get multiple lines.)

Comment: Can someone confirm that string.split() is available on most browsers (IE 8 and above?) I cant find any information about it online.

Comment: Yes, String.split is a core JavaScript feature that's available in all major browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`string.split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) like this:

```
var mystring="1=name1,2=name2,3=name3";
var arr = mystring.split(','); //array of ["1=name1", "2=name2", "3=name3"]
```

If you the want string version of result (unclear from your question), call `.join()` like this:

```
var newstring = arr.join(' '); //(though replace would do it this example)
```

Or loop though, etc:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  alert(arr[i]);
}
```

[You can play with it a bit here](http://jsfiddle.net/MQHkA/)

Comment: Please try not to use W3CSchools as a reference, in general.  Their information is often out of date, unreliable and they are in no way affiliated with the W3C.