# Javascript Split function

Tags: javascript

I am getting Date in this format (Fri May 13 2011 19:59:09 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time) )

Please tell me how can i use Javascript split function , so that i can get only May 13 2011 ??

Comment: possibility duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/3014740/668970

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could `split()` using space as the delimiter, `slice()` the required elements and then `join()` again with a space.

```
str = str.split(' ').slice(1, 4).join(' ');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/UwZac/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var date_split = date_string.split(" ");

var new_date_string = date_split[1]+" "+date_split[2]+" "+date_split[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expressions:

For this: /[\s][A-Za-z0-9]+[\s][0-9]+/

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lug6t/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make arrays of the string and manipulate the array members back to a string, but 
it is simpler to just cut the existing string at the space before the hours.

```
var D='Fri May 13 2011 19:59:09 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)';

alert(D.substring(0, D.search(/\s+\d{2}\:/))

/*  returned value: (String)
Fri May 13 2011 
*/
```