# How to detect and split email address using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

The email address is dynamic and The output should be:

Email Address:

> sample@email.com

Output should be:

> sample
>   
>   @email.com

Can JavaScript split the inputed email address?

Thank you guys!

Comment: `"sample@email.com".split("@")` -- > `["sample", "email.com"]` !

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript split function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014740/javascript-split-function)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the split method:

```
var str = "sample@email.com";
var res = str.split("@"); //An array, which looks like this [sample, email.com]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var email = foo@gmail.com
// variant 1 (without '@')
var mailArr = email.split('@');
var logn = mailArr[0];
var mailHost = mailArr[1];
// variant 2
var atPosition = email.indexOf('@');
var logn = email.slice(0, atPosition);
var mailHost = email.slice(atPosition, -1);
```

And for more common uses you should use regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way**

```js
const email='testEmail@gmail.com'
console.log(email.split('@')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

we can split using `split` method

```
var email = "demo@gmail.com";
var arry = email.split("@");
console.log(arry[0]) //demo
console.log(arry[1]) //gmail.com
```